# Why is Method of Moments not the MLE for Beta Distribution?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

This is a question from a statistics textbook: Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ form a random sample from the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Let $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ be the vector parameter. Show that the method of moments estimator is not the M.L.E.

Denote $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of method of moments, which is $\alpha = {m_1(m_1-m_2) \over m_2-m_1^2}$ and $\beta = {(1-m_1)(m_1-m_2) \over m_2-m_1^2}$, where $m_j = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n X^j_i$ for $j \ge 1$.

How to prove that the method of moments is not the MLE?

Comment: it would be helpful to write down the MLE estimate os $\alpha,\beta$ to compare.

Comment: @AlexR. I wrote down the MLE, and it seemed that there is no explicit form to express MLE in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Right, the MLE is solved via a polygamma equation. Usually method of moments estimators are biased, so if you know the MLE estimator is not biased, this would be a possible approach.

Comment: You say "Denote $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of the method of moments", but you appear to mean "Estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by the method of moments."   In comments you say there is no explicit form to express the MLE in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Might you mean there is no explicit expression of the MLE of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  The MLE should not be a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, hence should not be expressed in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Rather the MLE _for_ $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is a function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, and should be expressed in terms of those. $\qquad$

Comment: In other words, your language is confused.  Words have standard meanings.